# WC3 error for attribute needs id to be the same

Tags: html

I am getting an error that I do not understand what it means nor what is required to correct it.

The error "Any input descendant of a label element with a for attribute must have an ID value that matches that for attribute."

The referenced code:

```
 <p>Please prove you are human: <label for="code"> Write code in box &raquo; <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="color:#29372F; font-weight:bold;"></span><!-- this is where the script will place the generated code --> 
<input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" /></label><!-- this is where the script will place a copy of the code for validation: this is a hidden field -->
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: "I do not understand what it means" That's a lie. You were able to paraphrase the error in your question title just fine.

Comment: I'm working from someone else's stuff. I guess my real question is, if I change the for"" to for="txtCaptcha" will that interfere with the javascript. I know the script needs the txtCaptcha id to work. Just not sure if it needs the word code to work. JavaScript is not a strong point of mine.

Comment: @user1951143, if your real question is different from what you actually asked, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have provided "for" attribute in label , which indicates this label if is for which tag or component. You need to have some element with id "code". Change either id is that component to "code" , or change value of for attribute with that id.

```
 <label for="txtCaptchaDiv">
```